# How to create popup dialog page in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse plugin for my project. I want to have a popup dialog page when the user clicks a customized icon on the toolbar, kind of like [Google App Engine popup dialog](http://code.google.com/eclipse/images/deploy_dialog.png), any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

- a command
- a handler for the command
- a menu contribution for your toolbar
- a dialog

I have constructed a (very) small [example](http://rcp-company.com/uploads/demos/dialogex.zip) that illustrates this...

Comment: @Toony Madsen Thanks Tonny, your solution helps a lot!

Comment: your link is broken, do you have the alternate link?